# Magento Error after changed domain to new serwer

Tags: magento2

I have error website after changed domain from old to new store.

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 604561196452

```
{"0":"No such entity.","1":"#0 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreResolver\/Website.php(46): Magento\\Store\\Model\\WebsiteRepository->get('pl')\n#1 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreResolver.php(140): Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver\\Website->getAllowedStoreIds('pl')\n#2 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreResolver.php(126): Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->readStoresData()\n#3 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreResolver.php(89): Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->getStoresData()\n#4 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/StoreManager.php(157): Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId()\n#5 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Store\/Model\/StoreManagerInterface\/Proxy.php(119): Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManager->getStore(NULL)\n#6 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/Model\/Resolver\/Store.php(29): Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManagerInterface\\Proxy->getStore(NULL)\n#7 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Config\/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\\Store\\Model\\Resolver\\Store->getScope(NULL)\n#8 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Config.php(69): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL)\n#9 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/DesignExceptions.php(76): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config->getValue('design\/theme\/ua...', 'stores')\n#10 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/CacheIdentifierPlugin.php(43): Magento\\Framework\\View\\DesignExceptions->getThemeByRequest(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\CacheIdentifierPlugin->afterGetValue(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor), '4125c11ce523778...')\n#12 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#13 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/PageCache\/Identifier\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getValue', Array, Array)\n#14 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/PageCache\/Kernel.php(115): Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Identifier\\Interceptor->getValue()\n#15 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Kernel->load()\n#16 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#17 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#18 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#19 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#20 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#21 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#22 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/gerris.pl\/public_html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#23 {main}","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

EDIT:
I have update database but still no work.
[image]
[image]

also:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

no result

Comment: Execuet this in sql : `UPDATE \`customer_group\` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';`

Comment: I have update my topic.

Comment: Which Magento version you use?

Comment: Im work in magento 2.1.11 (other domain (old) work eg. gerris.cz ) so its no problem with magento only with configuration with new domain.

Comment: Backend working or not?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work (.PL is main domain with backend) (of course I have  try to upgrade deploy delete var folder etc but still no work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75482/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-sylvester).